# Is it possible to create in Aptana a Project with a different name to the containing folder?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I've been importing a number of project folders into Apatana 3 and some of them are stored on disk in folders with identical names.  It's not really easy for me to change the names of the folders themselves, as they are the same project on different servers (one is a local copy, the other a copy on a development server).

I tried importing the folder as a project and setting the name of the project to *FOLDERNAME - local* or *FOLDERNAME - dev* (depending on the location) but all that seems to do is create a new folder with the project name, rather than importing the specified project!

Is this normal behaviour and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling I managed to find a solution, hopefully this will help anyone who comes across the same issue:

When the Aptana workspace is set to the parent directory of a project, Aptana renames the project folder to match the project's name.  By setting the workspace to a different folder the project can be renamed without altering the folder name on disk.

I'm not entirely sure why Aptana does this, but changing the workspace does seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to import the project, right-click on it and rename it. The project name does not have to match the folder name. It may be how you are importing them...please follow the steps here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Importing+an+Existing+Project

Comment: I thought that would be the case, only every time I rename the project using that method it is also re-factoring the folder name on disk!  I'm wondering if perhaps I've somehow turned on a setting that links the two together?